# Compare the data in two different dataframe and see which are matching and not matching

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for a code to compare the columns in two data frames and create a new column in either of the data frames that shows that either the records match not matching or are not available

I want to compare if the ticket id has the same channel and plan in df2. If the ticket is not available then it should show ticket id not available.

in df2 channel_matching and plan_matching can be the new columns showing if the records are matching or not.

df1
ticket_id, channel, plan

1. ```
      email    A
   ```
2. ```
      msg.     B
   ```

df2
ticket_id, channel, plan channel_matching.  Plan_matching

1. ```
      msg      A.     Not matching.   Matching
   ```
2. ```
      msg.     B.     Matching.       Not matching
   ```
3. ```
      no ticket found.   no ticket found.    no ticket found
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just join the two dataframes and compare the columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'email', 'A'], [2, 'msg', 'B']], columns=['ticket_id', 'channel', 'plan'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'msg', 'A'], [2, 'msg', 'B']], columns=['ticket_id', 'channel', 'plan'])

df_all = df1.join(df2.set_index('ticket_id'), on='ticket_id', rsuffix='_r')
df_all['plan_matching'] = df_all['plan'] == df_all['plan_r']
```